# req.user being set to first user in database when trying to log in // Express, Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js

I'm working on an application using Node.js with the Express framework, using Passport for user authentication and MongoDB for storage.  I'm having trouble figuring out why no matter which user tries to log in, the server decides that the logged-in user is the first user in the database, i.e. the first user who signed up.

When the server receives a post request to /login, it runs passport.authenticate to authenticate the user's credentials.  From logging out to the console, it's clear that the proper user credentials are passed through, and even the session ID is correct, but wherever req.user is set, it is being set to the wrong user.

Here is a log in the console of what's happening to give you some idea:

```
get /user
--req.user is { salt: '$2a$10$NgPcBpvUqGq32IoWvsChd.',
  hash: '$2a$10$NgPcBpvUqGq32IoWvsChd.SYva2e/aaPsfUcdN65aRm/D1oYJB3Ty',
  username: 'daniel',
  email: 'dan@dan.com',
  _id: 515decd49fc3204ca1000001,
  __v: 0,
  songs: [] }
--req.session is { cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: true },
  passport: { user: '515decdc9fc3204ca1000002' },
  flash: {} }
```

As you can see, the user id is correct in req.sessions but incorrect in req.user.

The full code is available here:
https://github.com/patrickmestabrook/song-swap

Answer (score 2):

I would guess it is something to do with the serialize/deserialize process. Have you tried using _id.toString() in the serializeUser method?

Have you verified that the correct user is being returned inside 
**models.js**?

```
schemas.User.static('authenticate', function( username, password, done) {
  console.log('schemas.User.static.authenticate');
  console.log('-username is ' + username);
  console.log('-password is ' + password);


  this.findOne({ username: username }, function( err, user ) {
    console.log('this.findOne inside authenticate, callback');
    console.log('user.username is ' + user.username);

    if ( err   ) return done( err );
    if ( !user ) return done( null, false );
    user.verifyPassword( password, function( err, passwordCorrect) {


      if ( err ) return done( err );
      if ( !passwordCorrect ) { return done( null, false ); }
      // return done( null, user );
      done ( null, user );
    })
  })
})
```

Also check that the correct username and password are being passed to the authenticate method

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function( username, password, done ) {  
  console.log('username: ' + username)
  console.log('password: ' + password)
  models.User.authenticate( username, password, function( err, user) {
    // right now, this reports the WRONG USER DAMMIT
    console.log('models.User.authenticate callback');
    console.log('--username is ' + user.username);
    // return done( err, user );
    done( err, user);
  });

}));
```

Comment: I'm checking the user credentials at every point I can find.  What I can't find is the point at which req.user is set to a specific user.  Searching all files for 'req.user' in sublime text doesn't reveal the point at which req.user is set to the wrong user.  Any ideas?

Comment: I've now traced it up to the point where `passport.authenticate` calls `res.redirect('/user')` and console logging `req.user` at that point reports the correct user.  Where on earth could the wrong user be taking its place in the mean time?